# Setting camera positon or state for guiviewer3d

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

At what point/event is the earliest one may set the camera position or state when a viewer is initialized and a model is loaded?

Regards
Øyvind Knappskog Olsen
Norconsult Informasjonssystemer AS

Comment: I tried the MODEL_ROOT_LOADED_EVENT and it looks like that was the right time for setting my default state.

Answer (score 0):

That would be [Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/javascript/viewer3d/#geometry-loaded-event) which is fired whenever a model/drawing finishes loading.

Note this would get fired whenever Viewer completes the loading of a model so when you load multiple models be sure to implement some sort of check or remove the listener to prevent unwanted behavior.

Comment: As, I mentioned above, it looks like doing it as early as in  Autodesk.Viewing.MODEL_ROOT_LOADED_EVENT works fine. Then the viewer shows the model directly in a camera position i set as home. If I do it in Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT the model first shows as loaded and the switch to my preferred camera.